# Function for compressing a number range

Tags: functions

I'm working with TeX-Files which are converted from other formats. One thing that pops up in these are vertical lines in tables like the following:

```
\cline{1-1}\cline{2-2}...\cline{n-n}
```

This can be expressed in a compressed fashion as

```
\cline{1-n}
```

It is further complicated by the fact that multiple such ranges might appear in the same line, for example `1-5`, `7-11` and `15-17` all might appear on the same line, which prevents me from just looking for the first and last ones and using those.

I attempted to compress these with `query-replace-regexp`, where I tried to replace `\\cline{\([0-9]+\)-\1}\\cline{\,(+ 1 \#1)-\,(+ 1 \#1)}` with `\cline{\1-\,(+ 1 \#1)}`, which did not work. Can this be done, and if yes, how? Also I'd prefer this a an elisp-Macro so that I can easily reuse it.

Comment: I think you're really looking for an elisp *function* or command, not a macro.

Comment: @npostavs: Indeed, I changed the title of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code to "compress" each "cline sequence" in the buffer. To
use it do `M-x compress-all-cline-sequences`.

I may have gone a little overboard in generality: this handles the
case in which the clines are not in order or overlap in complicated
ways, for example, it will replace

```
\cline{1-3}\cline{9-13}\cline{11-15}\cline{5-7}\cline{4-4}
```

with

```
\cline{1-7}\cline{9-15}
```

Here's the code:

```
(defun compress-intervals (intervals)
  "Compress a list of intervals of integers given as a list of conses."
  (let ((compressed '())
        (left nil)
        (count 0))
    (dolist (pt (sort
                 (append
                  (mapcar (lambda (I) (cons (car I) 'start)) intervals)
                  (mapcar (lambda (I) (cons (1+ (cdr I)) 'end)) intervals))
                 (lambda (p q)
                   (or (< (car p) (car q))
                       (and (= (car p) (car q))
                            (eq (cdr p) 'start))))))
      (pcase (cdr pt)
        ('start (incf count)
                (unless left (setq left (car pt))))
        ('end (decf count)
              (when (zerop count)
                (push (cons left (1- (car pt))) compressed)
                (setq left nil)))))
    (nreverse compressed)))

(defun extract-cline-intervals (str)
  "Extract the intervals from a string of the form \\cline{a-b}\\cline{c-d}..."
  (let ((pos 0)
        (intervals '()))
    (save-match-data
      (while (string-match "\\\\cline{\\([0-9]+\\)-\\([0-9]+\\)}" str pos)
        (push (cons (string-to-number (match-string 1 str))
                    (string-to-number (match-string 2 str)))
              intervals)
        (setq pos (match-end 0))))
    (nreverse intervals)))

(defun compress-cline-sequence (str)
  "Compress a string of the form \\cline{a-b}\\cline{c-d}... to minimal form."
  (apply #'concat
         (mapcar (lambda (I) (format "\\cline{%d-%d}" (car I) (cdr I)))
                 (compress-intervals (extract-cline-intervals str)))))

(defun compress-all-cline-sequences ()
  "Find all sequences of consecutive clines in the buffer and compress each to minimal form."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\\(\\\\cline{[0-9]+-[0-9]+}\\)+" nil t)
      (replace-match (compress-cline-squence (match-string 0)) t t))))
```

---

**Edit for Emacs 24.3:**

As [Lupino](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/17213/lupino) pointed out in the comments, for Emacs 24.3 you need to do it like this:

```
(defun compress-intervals (intervals)
  "Compress a list of intervals of integers given as a list of conses."
  (let ((compressed '())
        (left nil)
        (count 0))
    (dolist (pt (sort
                 (append
                  (mapcar (lambda (I) (cons (car I) 'start)) intervals)
                  (mapcar (lambda (I) (cons (1+ (cdr I)) 'end)) intervals))
                 (lambda (p q)
                   (or (< (car p) (car q))
                       (and (= (car p) (car q))
                            (eq (cdr p) 'start))))))
      (pcase (cdr pt)
        (`start (incf count)
                (unless left (setq left (car pt))))
        (`end (decf count)
              (when (zerop count)
                (push (cons left (1- (car pt))) compressed)
                (setq left nil)))))
    (nreverse compressed)))

(defun extract-cline-intervals (str)
  "Extract the intervals from a string of the form \\cline{a-b}\\cline{c-d}..."
  (let ((pos 0)
        (intervals '()))
    (save-match-data
      (while (string-match "\\\\cline{\\([0-9]+\\)-\\([0-9]+\\)}" str pos)
        (push (cons (string-to-number (match-string 1 str))
                    (string-to-number (match-string 2 str)))
              intervals)
        (setq pos (match-end 0))))
    (nreverse intervals)))

(defun compress-cline-sequence (str)
  "Compress a string of the form \\cline{a-b}\\cline{c-d}... to minimal form."
  (message "str=%S" str)
  (apply #'concat
         (mapcar (lambda (I) (format "\\cline{%d-%d}" (car I) (cdr I)))
                 (compress-intervals (extract-cline-intervals str)))))

(defun compress-all-cline-sequences ()
  "Find all sequences of consecutive clines in the buffer and compress each to minimal form."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\\(\\\\cline{[0-9]+-[0-9]+}\\)+" nil t)
      (replace-match (compress-cline-sequence (match-string-no-properties 0)) t t)
)))
```

Comment: First of all , thanks a lot, it looks really impressive! However, If I try to run it, i get `Symbol's function definition is void: compress-cline-sequence`. Any idea why this happens? I use a fairly old emacs (24.3.1) on openSuse if that helps.

Comment: In 24.3 this only works if you replace 'start and 'end in (compress-intervals) by <backquote>start and <backquote>end respectively. (Backquotes are stacke exchange's control symbol for inline code, dammit. How can you escape those chars?!?)

Comment: Sorry, @Shylock, I've been away from Stack Exchange for a few days. I take it Lupino's change made it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your `\cline{...}`-statements are on a single line and you're interested in the range between the first and last digits, you can use

```
\\cline{\([0-9]+\).*\([0-9]+\)}$
```

to capture the first number after `\cline{` into a capturing group (denoted by `\(..\)`), then skip to the last number before the final `}` (using `.*` to skip everything inbetween, and `}$` to get the `}` at the end of the line) and store that in a second capturing group.

The replacement string then becomes

```
\\cline{\1-\2}
```

which inserts `\cline{`, then the string in the first capturing group (the first number), a `-`, the string in the second capturing group (the last number) and finally a `}`.

---

You can wrap this in a function using some extra backspace-escaping like this:

```
(defun compress-cline ()
  (interactive)
  (query-replace-regexp "\\\\cline{\\([0-9]+\\).*\\([0-9]+\\)}$"
                        "\\\\cline{\\1-\\2}"))
```

which you can then bind to a key, or call using `M-x compress-cline`.

Comment: Thanks, but I just realized that my question was oversimplifying the real issue. In fact it is usually multiple ranges, that's why this approach unfortunately won't work. I will edit the question accordingly.